# How can I configure Internet proxy on VM?

Tags: 10.04, networking, vmware, proxy

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on VMPlayer within Windows 7. Our corporation has just enforced an internet proxy, let's call it internet.largecompany.com:8443 for the sake of argument, and we can no longer get access to outside sites.

We can get access to the internet without any issues on Windows but no access at all from Ubuntu. I've tried changing the proxy settings in System>Preferences>Network Proxy along with providing my username and password but to no avail.

Any ideas? Anything I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.

I also should have added to my original question that we require authentication on the internet.largecompany.com:8443 proxy i.e. we get prompted for username and password.

Therefore, the way we resolved was to use the open source network tool [Cntlm Authentication Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/). This worked perfectly for our requirements.

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation about Cntlm configration

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Internet access in the web browser, change the network settings in the browser. It works for me through proxy server.

I have also not been able to make system wide Internet access work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more than likely due to the fact you have the Virtual Machine set up to use a NAT. As far as the Virtual Machine is concerned it is directly connected to the internet, the host machine (Windows 7) is supposed to forward any network traffic onto the "real" internet.

Like a lot of Virtual Machine software packages I would assume VMWare defaults to giving the guest operating system its own private network (NAT). This means that setting your proxy settings on the Ubuntu Guest won't work because it won't be able to communicate with the proxy server.

You will need to check in the VMWare settings if it can be configured to use a proxy. If not then the only solution would be to use Bridged Networking for your Virtual Machine. This passes all network traffic from the Virtual Machine **directly** onto the host's network. Be warned! this will look to your network admin as if you have plugged a new computer into an Ethernet port. Don't do this without checking with your network admin first!